# Python and Selenium, calling one test from another

Tags: python, selenium

Treat me gently, I'm no programmer!  Just started using Selenium to do some testing and what I am trying to do is recycle code, so I don't have to keep repeating and maintaining it.  So I have the following, which works perfectly;

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from mappings.home_mapping import *
from common.config import uname, pswd, baseurl

import unittest
import base64

class MyLogin(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = baseurl
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_login(self):
        driver = self.driver

        driver.get(self.base_url + "myurl/")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(el_username).clear()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(el_username).send_keys(base64.b64decode(uname))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(el_password).clear()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(el_password).send_keys(base64.b64decode(pswd))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(el_signin).click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException, e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

This just opens a new Firefox instance, takes me to my login page and logs me in.  It then closes the Firefox instance.

I can call that test from another test with the following;

```
from common import login
unittest.main(module = login)
```

What I want to do is call the same test, so it logs me in, but keep the window open so I can continue with more steps in my other test.  The reason for this is I probably have 50 tests to run, each of which require me to log in before navigating to the appropriate part of my app to test.

Is the answer as simple as not to use my login test but create another module which runs the login part and call that from my other tests?  Or can you guys thing of something even smarter.

Comment: Why not have a class-scoped [`setUpClass`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass) that creates the browser and logs you in once for all tests in the class? This would be in a separate class to the login test, which you could put all of the tests that rely on you already being logged in into.

Comment: Do you have an Api? If you do maybe you can do all the login via Api and just get to the part of the test you are interested. All the tests could call this method or class that logs in via the Api and just start to use the firefox browser from this point on. Similar to what @jonrsharpe suggests

Comment: @jonrsharpe - good answer but my tests are spread across a number of sub applications in the main app and I thought it would be good practice to keep all the tests separated by application.  Implementing your suggestion would reduce code maintenance, but I would still be left with 5 or 6 versions of it.  Is it possible to create a separate module that does the log in and passes the browser instance back to my test?

Comment: @NachoMiguel - no API, it's just a web app.

Comment: @PeterHolliday you could create a superclass, which inherits `unittest.TestCase` and implements `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` as appropriate, then inherit that for each set of related tests. This would reduce duplication while retaining a sensible test structure.