# Access webdriver variable to another def function

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-unittest

Given below issue steps while running the script.

- Open the Firefox Browser
- Open the Home Page of Website (Given the URL of Home Page)
- Click on Login Link
- Close the Browser
- Again Open the Browser
- Open the Home Page of Website

I have tried code from below URL but there is no answer.
[Python and Selenium, calling one test from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017691/python-and-selenium-calling-one-test-from-another)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
import time

class login(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="mylocalpath\\geckodriver.exe")
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("myurl")
        time.sleep(5)

    def test_LoginLink(self):
        self.link = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/a[2]")
        self.link.click()
        time.sleep(5)

    def test_forgot(self):

         driver = self.driver
         self.link1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/a")
         self.link1.click()
         time.sleep(3)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Why your tests have no assertions? Why do you want to pass something from one test to another? Note that test cases should be atomic and independent of each other. If you just want to automate some scenario - you don't have to use *Test Framework*

Comment: @Andersson
Thanks for the reply. Actually I want to create function for each and every action so I want to use driver in another function but page is different.